# Can't install Ubuntu one

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one

While trying to install Ubuntu one it throws me this error -

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/**DISTRIBUTION**/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found,
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/**DISTRIBUTION**/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found,
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

and I can't install it
Thanks.

Comment: Does the message say, literally, "DISTRIBUTION"? That string, and "PAckages" seem suspect.

Comment: Yea, well it's Packages, sorry for that.

Comment: DISTRIBUTION should be replaced by "precise" or "oneiric" or whatever, too.

Comment: There's not really a good reason to mask your distribution -- and if it was, say, `breezy` that'd be a handy clue that your problem is your distro.

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that the rabbitvcs ppa was incorrectly added to your system and it is blocking your access to all software.

I suggest that you open the software-center, then go to the Edit menu and to software sources. From there you can uncheck any references to the rebbitvcs ppa.

After you do that start a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try to install Ubuntu One again.

If you later want the rabbitvcs ppa back I suggest that you add it again using the instructions from [here](http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/install/ubuntu).

Comment: Well, actually now when i'm trying to update it throws me thos errors

Comment: You'll need to remove all of the offending sources before `apt-get update` will work. Please see also the question thread devav2 cites in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

That would seem to indicate you need to run "sudo apt-get update"

Answer (score 0):

Well, after looking up at the tutorial of installing rabbitvcs here - http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/install/ubuntu
I figured out that in the /etc/apt/sources.list file I entered **DISTURBUTION** instead of 12.04, but still after changing the line it gave me the same error so I just removed the rabbitvcs/ppa repo using this tutorial - http://penreturns.rc.my/2012/02/how-to-remove-purge-unofficial-ppa.html

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem: When I tried to use Ubuntu One by the first time, in my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed using custom DVD generated by Remastersys, it reports this error messages:

> W:Failed to check www.remastersys.com/Ubuntu/dists/precise/Release 
>   Unable to find expected entry 'main./source/Sources' in Release file
>   (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
>
> E:Some index failed to download. They have been ignored , or old ones used instead

Then must I uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu One ? (I will try)